# Unable to Make Mousewheel Stop At Div Above/Below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have divs that are, when viewed on desktop, on top of each other, with opacity linked to classes as shown below:

```
<div id="shell">
    <div class="box header is-active"></div>
    <div class="box not-active"></div>
    <div class="box footer not-active"></div>
</div>
```

I have some jquery/javascript that handles users using the arrow keys to move "up" and "down" the page, each action calling a specific function.

I also have a function that detects the mouse scroll and calls the up or down function as well.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        preDiv();
    }
    else {
        nextDiv();
    }
});
```

They both work but if you scroll "too fast" you skip over the next section. How do I make it so where when you scroll up or down, regardless of speed, it jumps only one div?

And of course, a jfiddle to show what I'm talking about with some css and my actual scripts being used:

https://jsfiddle.net/6d5nk79o/4/

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but your jsfiddle is extremely difficult to navigate whilst scrolling on my laptop trackpad - so you may want to take that into consideration also, if you have not already!

Comment: @Mark As in it jumps all of the divs on the slightest trackpad movement? Because that is exactly what I am having trouble with and hoping to fix!

Comment: Yep, thats the one. I'm afraid my jQuery is not good enough to be more helpful here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a cooldown interval after a mousewheel:

```
var cooldown = false;

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (cooldown)
        return;    

    cooldown = true;
    setTimeout(function() { cooldown = false; }, 1000);

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0)     {
        preDiv();
    }
    else {
        nextDiv();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dgwzaj36/

Comment: Of course! Thank you for putting in relation to my current function!

Answer (score 1):

Your code will feel a lot less… hair-triggered if you change your function to instead require a minimum cumulative `wheelDelta` amount from the last hop. This should help fight accidental scrolls on touchpads and such.